# How to synchronise Drupal 8 fields with external data sources?

Tags: synchronization, drupal-8

I have fields in entities (specifically content types and taxonomies) that I would like to populate and synchronise with external data sources. Am I right in thinking that this can be implemented using `hooks` and/or `events`?

I need to be able to read data from the external source into a field and, if it changes, write the new value back again.

While searching for information I found a module called `external_entities` that sounded promising, but needs a plugin to do what I want. Can anyone explain how to implement such a plugin and whether it is a better approach than hooks and events?

Steve

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to implement one cron job to check the external Sorce and put it in a queue you can split the work into small parts.

to the start in `hook_cron`:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/function/hook_cron/8.2.x

how you can implement a `QueueWorker` you need to work off your queue:
https://knackforge.com/blog/vamsi/how-create-queue-woker-drupal-8

In your `QueueWorker`, you have the option to load the nodes you need and update the field of them

Comment: Thanks for this. However,  I’m looking more for an ‘on-demand’ solution whereby the field looks for its value from the external resource rather than the Drupal database and updates that external resource if its value is changed. Perhaps ‘synchronise’ is the wrong term.